# How to maximize the product xy?

Tags: calculus

$2x + 3y = 20$. Find the values of x and y that **maximize** the product $xy$.

Is this meant to be an **implicit differentiation problem**? So, it would be $y'' = 2x + 3yy'$?

Is there anything else to do, or is that it? I don't understand.

Comment: If $2x+3y=20$ then $x=\frac12 (20-3y)=10-\frac32 y$ and so $xy=$ ?

Comment: The gradient of the constraint is $(2,3)$ and so $xy$ is maximized when $\nabla xy=(y,x)$ is proportional to that. Hence you get $(x,y)=(5,10/3)$ as the solution, and a product of $50/3$.

Comment: Where does the 1/2 come from?

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

$$4(2x)(3y)=(2x+3y)^2-(2x-3y)^2\le(2x+3y)^2=?$$

Comment: Where does the 4 come from? Where do the exponents come from? Why is there a less than or equal sign?

Comment: @user6050977,  Expand $$(a+b)^2-(a-b)^2$$  and for real $u, u^2\ge0\iff-u^2\le0$

Answer (score 2):

$$xy=x(\frac{20-2x}{3})$$

Now you have a single variable optimization.

Comment: So, y is replaced by 20-2x/3?

Comment: @user6050977, yes

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively we are maximizing $$(2x)\cdot(3y)\ \ \ \ \text{with constraint}\ \ \  2x+3y=20.$$ That's the same as maximizing $uv$ with constraint $u+v=20$, and the maximum here is clearly given by $u=v=10$ (AM-GM) and so we see that $$2x=3y=10$$ is the solution.

Comment: What does AM-GT mean?

Comment: @user6050977  The reference AM-GM is to the Arithmetic Mean-Geometric Mean Inequality $$\frac{a + b}{2} \geq \sqrt{ab}$$ for $a, b > 0$.  Equality holds if and only if $a = b$.